# c++ vector implementation - move constructor - move vs forward

Tags: c++, c++11, move, forward, rvalue-reference

Under MSVC2010 the definition of move constructor for `vector` class is the following :

```
vector(_Myt&& _Right)
    : _Mybase(_Right._Alval)
    {   // construct by moving _Right
    _Assign_rv(_STD forward<_Myt>(_Right));
    }
```

As there is also a definition of a copy constructor, I guess we never call `vector(_Myt&& _Right)` with a lvalue reference as argument.

So I'm wondering if here, this line :

```
_Assign_rv(_STD forward<_Myt>(_Right));
```

could be replace by :

```
_Assign_rv(_STD move<_Myt>(_Right));
```

with no side effect

Comment: +1 for exploring your STL. It's hard work, but understanding comes at a price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for a type without reference qualifiers `T`, both `std::forward<T>` and `std::forward<T&&>` are just fancy ways of saying `std::move`.

Comment: This is the first time I see this assertion and, if true it may clarify many use cases. So for example in this expression `template<class T> fun(T&& t){ ... }`, is `T` guaranteed to be "without reference qualifiers"? if so why then usually `std::forward<T>(t)` appears in the body of these type of functions (instead of a simpler `std::move(t)`)?

Comment: @alfC No, it isn't guaranteed to be "without reference qualifiers". If so, then an rvalue was passed in. If an lvalue was passed in, `T` will be `U&` and reference collapsing turns `U& &&` into `U&`. You can read more about this if you search for "universal references c++"

Comment: So that is why, when forwarding a "universal reference" (to do perfect forward) it is necessary to do it with `std::forward<T>(t)`, (in case the lvalue is passed.)